# Function extending with if query in functions.php

Tags: functions, title

the following function I was producing together with some users here and it is function perfectly.

```
   add_filter('wpseo_set_title', 'wpseo_set_title_callback');
    $meinungen = "Meinungen zu: ";

    function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {

        $page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');

        if (is_single() && $page_comment > 0) {
            global $meinungen;
            return ''. $meinungen . ''. $input . ''; 
        } else {
            return ''. $input . ''; 
        }

    }
```

Now I wanna extend this function in this point, that I wanna say if "$page_comment"  more than 3 "$meinungen" is "Kontroverse Diskussionen zu". In all other cases "$meinungen" stays on "Meinungen zu",

I tryed like it follows, but it doesnt function...I think the reason could be, that the query of comes later, but I dont know, how to get this in a point. Perhaps somebody could help me ?

```
   add_filter('wpseo_set_title', 'wpseo_set_title_callback');


if $page_comment > 3) {
            $meinungen = "Kontroverse Diskussionen zu: "; 
        } else {
           $meinungen = "Meinungen zu: ";
        }




    function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {

        $page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');

        if (is_single() && $page_comment > 0) {
            global $meinungen;
            return ''. $meinungen . ''. $input . ''; 
        } else {
            return ''. $input . ''; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Theres a syntax error in your if statement, you're also trying to test `$page_comment` before it exists, and you're doing it outside of the function. It's equivalent to going through a shopping list at the supermarket, then suddenly being at an airport 2 weeks in the past picking up milk

Comment: Yes, I thought this...like I wrote, but I dont know how to solve it. Do you know ?

Comment: a lot of this is basic fundamental PHP, I **strongly** recommend you read up on the basics, an hour of reading should make a massive improvement. This is WP development and people here will assume you know what a function is and basic concepts such as scope and global variables. If you don't have a grasp on what these are then you won't understand the answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be it's clearer like this :

```
add_filter('wpseo_set_title', function ($title) {


    if (is_single()) {

        $page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');

        if ($page_comment > 3) {

            $title = "Kontroverse Diskussionen zu: $page_comment $title";

        } elseif ($page_comment > 0) {

            $title = "Meinungen zu: $page_comment $title";

        }

    }


    return $title;

});
```

Comment: OK thanks and the rest stays like it is ?

Comment: Function very well BUT WER ARE MISSING "'. $input . '" from the original Source...function wpseo_set_title_callback($input)...but how to put that in code ? The rest is perfect !

Comment: Exactly to say: "$title;" (what is comming out of your function) must be inserted in "$meinungen" of our function above

Comment: it's easier to read at the end of the line, I edited the code

Comment: Sorry you missunderstand...look at the posting belöov of "black"...In this direction it has to go. Only problem at the moment: The code from black doesent function. But in your source the wohle "wpseo_set_title_callback" with "input" is missing and so it gives out not the original input, only my things under "title".

Comment: PERFECT ! Withour "$page_comment" before Title its function perfectly ! Many thanks !

Comment: @mmm this answer doesn't actually answer what the problem was, it just provides copypaste. In this scenario the Original Asker doesn't understand why their code is failing and still doesn't, so I wouldn't provide copypasta and instead avoid a full code example in favour of explaining the problem, especially considering that there is fundamental PHP missing here, it would have been a good opportunity to explain function scope

Answer (score 1):

Mmh. I cannot understand your requests. Do you want the function **intact**, without changes, as the original one? So, you want to extend the code only **outside the function**? If yes, probably you simply need the following:

```
  <?php 

    global $meinungen;
    $page_comment = get_query_var('cpage');

        if ($page_comment > 3) {
            $meinungen = "Kontroverse Diskussionen zu: "; 
        } else {
           $meinungen = "Meinungen zu: ";
        }

add_filter('wpseo_set_title', 'wpseo_set_title_callback');

    function wpseo_set_title_callback($input) {
        global $page_comment;
        if (is_single() && $page_comment > 0) {

            return ''. $meinungen . ''. $input . ''; 
        } else {
            return ''. $input . ''; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need...I need the function intact like before, only change: til 3 pages $meinungen = "Meinungen zu: ";, over 3 pages $meinungen = "Kontroverse Diskussionen zu: "; . I was testing this now, but it happens nothing. Anyhow there must be some small mistake

Comment: Probably solved. Try now.

Comment: unfortunately not ! Happens NOTHING ! Its showing only the original title, nothing more !

Comment: are you on a page or a post?

Comment: on a post ! The function that we made before ist perfect. The only thing that I need more ist like I told that til 3 pages $meinungen = "Meinungen zu: ";, over 3 pages $meinungen = "Kontroverse Diskussionen zu: "

Comment: Look above I have a function script :)